# newtxmath set braces

Tags: fonts, newtxmath, newtx

The behavior of set braces in `newtxmath` has recently changed for me. I can't find any indication of this change in [the documentation](http://mirror.las.iastate.edu/tex-archive/fonts/newtx/doc/newtxdoc.pdf). I'm wondering what has happened, if it might be a bug, and if the previous behavior (which I was fond of) is easily restored.

Previously, the midway point in the brace was (infamously) subtle, which led to the inclusion of the `cmbrace` option, discussed in the documentation. But now `cmbrace` seems to be the default, and I don't see a way to turn it off. The following produces the same output regardless of whether `cmbrace` is on or off (and toggling `bigdelims` has no effect):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage[cmbraces]{newtxmath}
\begin{document}
$\{$\{
\end{document}
```

The braces in normal mode are close to the previous math braces, though not identical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the documentation Chapter 14 "Appendix: Changes made in version 1.5" you find the innocent looking

> The overly small delimiters ([{ in Times are no longer used in math mode, being replaced by bigger versions. The former option `bigdelims` no longer has any effect.

What does this have to do with `cmbraces`? After this change, `bigdelim` is the default and `bigdelim` overwrites `cmbraces`, therefore `cmbraces` is now ignored. You could get back to `cmbraces` my manually adding

```
\DeclareMathDelimiter{\lbrace}{\mathopen}{lettersA}{62}{largesymbols}{142}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{\rbrace}{\mathclose}{lettersA}{63}{largesymbols}{143}
```

to your preamble, but as far as I can tell the original braces have been overwritten in the font, so they can not be restored without changing the font.

Comment: Well spotted, that does seem to solve it. This seems like a less than ideal way to have implement this change. I can understand changing the default behavior, but making it impossible to revert to the old behavior?